# Problem With Setting Tags While Adding Views Programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, foreach

While adding a `TextView` and two `ImageView`s to root `ConstraintLayout` and setting constraints programmatically, something weird happens while I am setting `Tag`s of the views.

Here is how I create aforementioned views and add them to view:

```
    val confirmLocationText = TextView(context!!)
    confirmLocationText.text = "Confirm?"
    confirmLocationText.textSize = 20f
    confirmLocationText.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
    confirmLocationText.measure(0, 0)

    val confirmLocationTickImage = ImageView(context!!)
    confirmLocationTickImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick)
    confirmLocationTickImage.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP

    val confirmLocationCancelImage = ImageView(context!!)
    confirmLocationCancelImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel)
    confirmLocationCancelImage.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP

    arrayOf(confirmLocationCancelImage, confirmLocationTickImage,confirmLocationText).forEach {
        it.id = View.generateViewId()
        it.tag = confirmInterfaceTag
        it.alpha = 0f
        viewToBeCreated?.eventMapFragmentRootConstraintLayout?.addView(it)
        it.animate().alpha(1f).duration = confirmInterfaceFadeInFadeOutAnimation // Fade-In animation for Confirm Interface
    }
```

And after this piece of code, I set constraints programmatically by using `ConstraintSet`.

The problem occurs in the `forEach`. It only runs twice but all three of views are added anyway (Although one of the `ImageView`s don't have assigned tag but animation works). When I remove `confirmLocationCancelImage` (or `confirmLocationTickImage`) from `arrayOf`, it again runs twice but this time the removed `ImageView` won't be added.

So I don't understand:

1) Why `forEach` runs twice?

2) When it runs twice, why three of the views are added?

3) And when it runs twice and three of the views are added then why one of them misses tag?

I hope it is not a silly question but seemed weird and annoying to me. Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT: When I change the code as below, it works but I still don't understand why it doesn't work as it above...

```
    val confirmLocationText = TextView(context!!)
    confirmLocationText.text = "Confirm?"
    confirmLocationText.textSize = 20f
    confirmLocationText.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
    confirmLocationText.measure(0, 0)

    val confirmLocationTickImage = ImageView(context!!)
    confirmLocationTickImage.apply {
        setImageResource(R.drawable.tick)
        id = View.generateViewId()
        tag = confirmInterfaceTag
        alpha = 0f
        viewToBeCreated?.eventMapFragmentRootConstraintLayout?.addView(this)
        animate().alpha(1f).duration = confirmInterfaceFadeInFadeOutAnimation
        scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
    }

    val confirmLocationCancelImage = ImageView(context!!)
    confirmLocationCancelImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel)
    confirmLocationCancelImage.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP

    arrayOf(confirmLocationCancelImage,confirmLocationText).forEach {
        it.id = View.generateViewId()
        it.tag = confirmInterfaceTag
        it.alpha = 0f
        viewToBeCreated?.eventMapFragmentRootConstraintLayout?.addView(it)
        it.animate().alpha(1f).duration = confirmInterfaceFadeInFadeOutAnimation // Fade-In animation for Confirm Interface
    }
```

Comment: How do you know your forEach only ran twice?

Comment: @Anton I just simply print from forEach and it prints to logcat only twice.

Comment: Is your print statement the first statement in your forEach, before `it.id = View.generateViewId()`?

Comment: @Anton Yes, it is the first line.

Comment: Weird :), could you make your prints the only line in your forEach and see if it then prints three times?

Comment: @Anton When prints are the only lines in forEach - it still prints twice. But what I noticed just now is when I print at the first and also last line of forEach, it prints three times for each (i.e., 6 in total) so working correctly - I have no idea why :)

Comment: Very strange, in that case I am out of ideas.